# Quality of Flash playback on Lubuntu 11.04 is bad

Tags: 11.04, flash, lubuntu

As the title says it is bad with a lot of tearing. The strange thing is that with the standard Ubuntu (classic mode no effects) it works smoothly, better than ever before it seems by the way.

- ATI HD 4350 with proprietary drivers through Additional Drivers
- The latest Firefox 5.0 (or Chromium, doesn't matter)
- Latest Flash
- tried `lubuntu-desktop` on "top of" Ubuntu
- tried `lxde-core` on "top of" Ubuntu
- tried Lubuntu with the "standalone" install disk

Always the same results. I really like LXDE for its speed/responsiveness and Ubuntu, but this is a big show stopper.

Does anybody has the same/similar issues? I find it really strange and from a noob's perspective it makes no sense and is almost not excusable. ;)

EDIT: Sorry for the missing piece of info.

I use the Adobe Flash package from the Canonical Partner Repository. 
No Flash Aid with Firefox. My understanding was that Chromium doesnt come with the build in flash ?

Comment: Latest Flash from? Are you using Flash Aid add-on for Firefox, or the latest Flash that comes with Google Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I edited my Question to include the missing info.

Comment: If your graphic card supports it you can always try to run compiz under lubuntu.

Comment: No, Chromium doesn't com with Flash, *Chrome* does. Do try Flash Aid and see if it helps.

Comment: @Javier, I doubt Compiz has much to do with Flash.

Comment: @Oxwivi: The only difference between running firefox under Ubuntu and Lubuntu is the window manager. If he has a good video card, compiz will stress the CPU less than openbox. I know it's just a blind shot, this is why make it a comment than an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)